# NSURLSession, завершение загрузки

Tags: objective-c, xcode, сессия, download

Ищу метод, который вызывается в NSURLSession только при завершении загрузки

Начало загрузки выглядит так:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]; // URL
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                              {
                                                  if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && error == nil){

                                                      id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                                      [_tableViewData addObject:object];
                                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                          // обновление UI
                                                      });
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }];
```

Comment: Ваш completionHandler вызывается после завершения загрузки (как уже отметили в ответе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вас завершения происходит в completionHandler: блоке. Если вы хотите чтобы ваш запрос обрабатывался при завершении тогда попробуйте подключить методи делегата:

```
<NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>
```

к своему класса.
Создайте запрос:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
```

В NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate есть метод который вызывается при завершении запроса:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
}
```

В нем обрабатываете ваши данные по запросу.